# Add property to HtmlElement

Tags: typescript, vue.js

[[WARNING]]: It looks like the question [TypeScript: add type property to HtmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590162/typescript-add-type-property-to-htmlelement) but I need to add a function to an Element Object but not add an attribute to a Node.

I try to make JavaScript to TypeScript but I am new with TypeScript, I try to add a new
function to `el.clickOutsideEvent`, but ts do not allow me to do like this:

```js
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el: HTMLElement, binding: Object, vnode: VNode) {
    // stack-overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389266/13031497
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event: MouseEvent): void {
      if (!(el == event.target) ||
            event.target instanceof Node && el.contains(event.target)) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    }
    // ugly, but fix the bug:
    // 2020/11/20 - Peterlits Zo
    // When I click the the ellipsis-h buttom, it do not change anything.
    // I find that itself call this function auto, so I add this after times.
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    }, 50)
  },
  unbind: function (el: HTMLElement) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
})
```

It tell me that: `Property 'clickOutsideEvent' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.` and something else.

What should I do for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom interface extending from `HTMLElement`.

```js
interface IHTMLElementClicketyClick extends HTMLElement {
  clickOutsideEvent?(event: MouseEvent): void;
}

Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el: IHTMLElementClicketyClick, binding: Object, vnode: VNode) {

  // the rest of the code
```

Comment: It tell me that `el` and `el` are incompatible... Well, because I change the type of function `bind`, it cannot work now.

Comment: Hm, in that case, we need to make this method optional by adding a question mark (`?`) after the method name. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to extent the HTMLElement type using [module-augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/js/@types"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

**src/js/@types/app.d.ts**

```
interface HTMLElement {
    clickOutsideEvent(event: MouseEvent): void
}
```

Comment: Well, sad to find that it raise a error with `el and el are incompatible`. I add:
``` typescritpt
interface HTMLElement {
  clickOutsideEvent(event: MouseEvent): void;
}
```
But then the original `HTMLElement` is not compatible with the new one. (How to edit code block in comment?)

Comment: I would avoid doing it this way as this will apply to all definitions of `HTMLElement` which is not necessarily right. Imagine you have another directive that has nothing to do with mouse clicks (say `v-mouse-hover`), this `clickOutsideEvent` will also be exposed there, which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare custom properties on global.

```
declare global {
    interface HTMLElement {
        clickOutsideEvent: (event: MouseEvent) => void
    }
}
```

Another *bad* approach is using `@ts-ignore`.

```
// @ts-ignore
el.clickOutsideEvent = clickOutsideEvent
```

Comment: I think that new interface maybe is a better idea?

Comment: I can't understand your point. Do you mean 'new interface' as custom interface instead of extending `HTMLElement`? If then, yes it's better, if it's possible.